# Programmatical solution to list all @Schedule and programmatical Timers in JEE7

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, wildfly, wildfly-8, timer-jobs

I am wondering if there is a way to get all JEE7 Timers with their crons from a container.

We are right now using wildfly, but it would be nice to get a solution for all JEE7 containers.

We need the list of timers to visualize on a UI, so it must be a way, there we can programmatically fetch all timers from the container.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you  http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_2_listing_all